# Sort a csv with python from standard input

Tags: python, sorting, csv

This is my python script for sorting by column a csv file read from stdin:

```
with  sys.stdin as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(2))
  for row in sortedlist:
     print(','.join(row)),
     print('\n'),
```

I run the command in order to sort by 3rd column(zero indexed is 2):

```
./sorter1.py < test.csv > test_sorted.csv
```

and the sorted file test_sorted.csv is:

```
31,53,101,122 
88,95,103,59 
66,58,104,50 
93,46,105,52 
88,88,118,107 
**115,57,31,34** 
110,87,36,63 
32,108,36,107 
75,35,57,35 
99,46,57,28 
41,35,67,59 
108,99,98,35 
36,66,98,60
```

It is like sorted two files and merged it. Is it a matter of buffer size of the reader or a matter of sorted method?

**This sorts alphabetically not numerically**

Comment: Where was `column` defined and what value is it?

Answer (score 1):

> This sorts alphabetically not numerically

You'll have to *cast* the sort column values to integer in order to sort numerically. I have replaced the sort function with a `lambda` that includes the conversion to `int`:

```
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=lambda x: int(x[2]))
```